# How to compute cityblock for N dimention matrice?

Tags: python, pytorch

I am going to compute the Manhattan distance for two [4,12,64,32]matrices using scipy.spatial.distance.cdist. However, cdist(x,y,'cityblock') does not support to compute cityblock distance for >3d matrices. I manually implement it like

```
T=4
A=torch.randn([T,12,64,32],dtype=torch.float)
B=torch.randn([T,12,64,32],dtype=torch.float)
manhattan_dist=manhattan_dist(A,B)
def manhattan_dist(self, q, k):
    _, B, H, N, C = q.shape
    out = [[0 for i in range(H)] for i in range(B)]

    for b in range(0, B):
        for h in range(0, H):
            dist = cdist(q.squeeze().detach().cpu().numpy()[b][h], k.squeeze().detach().cpu().numpy()[b][h],
                         metric='cityblock')
            out[b][h] = dist

    out = torch.tensor(np.array(out)).unsqueeze(0).float()
    return out
```

, which runs very slowly.

I would like to ask how I can use cuda() to compute the Manhattan distance for the two [4,12,64,32]matrices parallelly.

Comment: Isn't [`torch.dist`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.dist.html#torch.dist) with `p = 1` exactly what you need?

Comment: I think `scipy.spatial.distance.cdist` might not be doing what you expect it to do. It takes two collections of vectors and gives back the distance matrix for these two collections, i.e. computes the distance between every vector from the first collection with every vector from the second collection. The output from your call to `cdist` should therefore be a 64x64 matrix. Your question sounds like you want a scalar in the end, but the code looks like you are fine with a 4x12 matrix. Or do you actually want the [4,12,64,64] tensor produced by that code?